# Is there an output stream besides cout in C++?

Tags: c++, language-design, cout

My C++ book gives the following example regarding `cout`:

```
cout << "literals" << "to be" << "printed" ;
```

Then, it goes on to say:

> The statements starts with the name of the output stream, *cout*

This seems to imply that there are other streams. Are there other output streams besides `cout` in C++? What are they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some examples:

- The `std::cerr` **value** from `<iostream>` - standard error stream
- The `std::fstream` **type** from `<fstream>` - file input and file output streams
- The `std::stringstream` **type** from `<sstream>` - string streams

Comment: This answer is confusing, because std::cerr is an _instance_ of a std::ostream, while std::fstream and std::stringstream are types.

Comment: @Mooing Duck, but I mentioned it explicitly in my answer. I'll bold that of you think it's not clear enough. :)

Answer (score 5):

For one, there's cerr that writes to standard error. Then there's any other stream you can make yourself such as a file stream, e.g.

```
ofstream mystream = ofstream("myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 5):

The C standard defines 3 common file descriptors:

- stdin (for user input)
- stdout (for output)
- stderr (for error messages)

In C++, they are available as streams.

- std::cin
- std::cout
- std::cerr

cin is an input stream. cout and cerr are both output streams.

Comment: There's also `std::clog` in C++.

Comment: @Chris: but that also writes to `stderr`; the difference with `cerr` is that `clog` is buffered.

Answer (score 3):

By default, there's also `cerr` for standard error. You can also open new output streams.

Answer (score 3):

First, an output stream is just an object of a class that provides a stream which somehow outputs data somewhere - normally of the c++ IOstream library, e.g. [Ostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/ostream/).

- `std::cout` is the stream writing to the **standard** output
- `std::cerr` is the stream writing to the **standard** error channel

That's normally what you use when writing console applications.

Then there are

- filestreams to write to files
- stringsreams to build/modify strings

See this diagram of the [IOstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/) library, visualizing all c++ streams in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

For example (from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/) there are these stream:

```
cerr     Standard output stream for errors (object )
clog     Standard output stream for logging (object )
```

But what do you mean with "output" stream? "console" output stream? output "wherever" stream?

From the same site (but different page http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cerr/)

> By default, most systems have their standard error and logging output directed to the console, where text messages are shown, although this can generally be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

printf is one way to do it

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

```
printf ("Hello world");
```

Comment: Wrong language, this is C++. Plus, this isn't even a file handle, `stdout` would be the closest equivalent to `cout`.

Comment: Language is ok, as printf is available from C++ too. But the answer is totally out of topic.

Comment: printf is a C++ function and it uses standard output >.>

Comment: It's part of the c++ standards so it's c++

Answer (score 0):

There is cerr, but it's not the same as cout.  It's designed for output error.

As far as the standard streams go, there are different ways to access them (for example, using stdout/stderr like file handles to fwrite), but there are only 2 of them at the end of the day:

stdout - Designed for standard output.  Program status, useful data, so on.
stderr - Designed for output describing errors.  Often also used for debugging data.

Sometimes actual output will be done on stdout and progress or debugging related output on stderr.  That way, the user can pipe stdout into a file and leave stderr going to the console.  This allows them to both capture desired information and see progress and whatnot.